# app crashes when another activity is called (logcat provided)

Tags: android, logcat

i'm programming a little app which displays data from a website. The data is provided as a json string. i had 3 activities which worked fine. now i changed the code of one activity and wanted to test it. but since then none of the activities are working anymore and i dont find the error with the debugger. maybe someone can help me with the logcat.

Thx

```
08-23 08:17:09.600: E/Trace(641): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-23 08:17:10.368: D/dalvikvm(641): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 93K, 2% free 10954K/11143K, paused 60ms, total 64ms
08-23 08:17:10.738: D/gralloc_goldfish(641): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-23 08:17:32.118: D/AndroidRuntime(641): Shutting down VM
08-23 08:17:32.118: W/dalvikvm(641): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaughtexception (group=0x40a13300)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.damps.fantasy/de.damps.fantasy.scoresActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at de.damps.fantasy.Json.readUrl(Json.java:39)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at de.damps.fantasy.Json.<init>(Json.java:20)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at de.damps.fantasy.scoresActivity.parse(scoresActivity.java:110)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at de.damps.fantasy.scoresActivity.onCreate(scoresActivity.java:34)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-23 08:17:32.260: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  ... 11 more
08-23 08:17:32.399: D/dalvikvm(641): GC_CONCURRENT freed 227K, 3% free 11198K/11463K, paused 77ms+106ms, total 270ms
```

Comment: [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) indicates that you are doing network operations on main thread. Which is a really bad idea. You need to have [strict mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) enabled or using a SDK version higher or equal than HONEYCOMB to get this. You can workaround it by changing the SDK version required for your app or disable it using strict mode, but this is a really bad idea except you are making some trials.

Comment: found the mistake i made or what i changed.
i added android:targetSdkVersion in the manifest. but i will look to use asynctask now thx for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing some network activity in that Activity on the Main UI thread. This will raise an exception whenever your build target is set to honeycomb or higher. To fix it reduce the build target, or move the Network operation to it's own [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some network operation in UI thread, avoid long running tasks which dont need UI, in some other thread, by following link you can do achieve this:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Comment: not really i access the website and get the string, parse it into a JSONObject and fill a tableview with it. its not much data anyway. as i said it already worked fine

Comment: Since android 3.0 Api level 11, any operation which need network access must be implemented into some other thread or async task, and as you are accessing a website, and parsing data into json, you are using network thread, and most probably the code block where you called this code might be in some other thread, or async task code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement an AsynTask when you're downloading the datas from the website.

Example :

Use AsyncTask :

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Result>{
                    private Activity activity;
                    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
                        super();
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading", "Loading", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Result doInBackground(Void... v) {
        //do your stuff here
        return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Finished.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

}

Call it from the activity:

```
MyAsyncTask task = new AsyncTask(myActivity.this);
task.execute();
```